# How to prevent air bubbles in spray painting cabinets

Tags: cabinets, repainting, spraypainting

I am redoing my cabinets. My primer and first coat of paint went on flawlessly - a beautiful finish. I have done all the prep properly, like sanding between coats, but for some reason I keep getting air bubbles that are leaving craters when it dries.

I am using Benjamin Moore Advanced with a Graco 360.

Any advice to fix this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: (You can fix and improve your question using the "[edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/235234/edit)" link just below your post.)

Comment: Sounds like offgassing. Did you wait a sufficient amount of time between coats for your climate?

Comment: Yes,I waited 6 days to do the second coat.

Comment: If you are using spray paint, keep the coating thin and without overlapping. Wait for it thoroughly dries, then add the next thin coat in the orthogonal direction to the first.